# Unable to connect to database from Docker

Tags: python, linux, docker, odbc, pyodbc

I cannot figure out the correct way of arranging the configuration files needed to connect to an external database from a Docker container. The whole thing is running on Windows, and the Docker is Debian, and I'm using FreeTDS as per [this tutorial](https://tryolabs.com/blog/2012/06/25/connecting-sql-server-database-python-under-ubuntu/) to make a connection. I've also been following suggestions in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723656/whats-causing-unable-to-connect-to-data-source-for-pyodbc).

With the very helpful Flask debugger, I'm able to tell that I'm connecting to the server with the following connection string:

```
'DSN=server_name; DATABASE=db_name; UID=usr; PWD=pw'
```

These are the contents of my configuration files:

```
# odbcinst.ini in /etc/ and /
[FreeTDS]
Description = FreeTDS driver
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so

# odbc.ini in /etc/ and /root/.odbc.ini
[data_source]
Driver = FreeTDS
Servername = server_name
Port = 1433
Database = db_name

# freetds.conf in /etc/freetds/
[global]
tds version = 7.4

[server_name]
host = server_ip
port = 1433
```

> [IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)

However, I can connect to the database with the command line using `tsql -H server_ip -p 1433 -U usr -P pw`. `isql -v data_source username pwd` works too. `osql` gives the following error:

> path/libtdsodbc.so is not an executable file
>
> osql: error: no driver found for data_source

I can't figure out the problem.. Doesn't help I'm pretty inexperienced with Linux as well. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is your database dockerized as well ? When you say you're able to connect to the database, is it from within the Docker container ?

Comment: @Mornor I see my explanation was very ambigous, fixed now. Sorry.

Comment: Did you expose the port `:1433` of the Docker image? So, in a Dockerfile: `EXPOSE 1433` and the Docker command: `docker run -p 1433:1433 [...] `

Comment: Could the down- and closevoter provide some insight as to how might this post be improved? Or is it not on topic?

Comment: @Mornor Exposed, didn't help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure it out with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12370754/7089239) on the linked question. It wasn't a straight-out fix, because the configuration is still not working, but it's a bypass and good enough.

The trick was to call `pyodbc.connect` with keyword arguments instead of a connection string. To copy from the link:

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect(
    driver = 'FreeTDS',
    TDS_Version = '7.4',
    server = '<hostname or ip address>',
    port = 1433,
    database = '<database>',
    uid = '<uid>',
    pwd = '<pwd>'
)
```

The fix was particularly strange as I don't think the official Wiki for PyODBC mentions the keyword argument version at all.

In addition, now only the `odbcinst.ini` file is needed for configuration, so that saves at least some hassle with the container build.